# NHibernate ASP.NET and Encrypted Connection strings Error

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, connection-string

I get an error:
Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0

in teh nhibernate config section of the web.config I have this set to use the named connection string:
MyConnectionString

And when I try it I get an error, now this worked fine with unencrypted connection string, I thought it would work with an encrypted one, but I'm guessing now, since I think the above error is stating that something is wrong with my connection string, but unencrypted it works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you show us the snippet of your web.config? Encrypted connection strings work very well for me. Perhaps - could you try the same connection string with direct connection to database i.e. without NH..?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was one that I would not have ever guessed. The encrypted connection string is not the standard encrypted connection string. It is encrypted with a custom encryption schema and then added to the config file. So I had to make a helper that decrypted the connection string first then pass it to the nhibernate configuration.

Big pain but standard encryption mechanics fro the .NET config work correctly it seems, good to know.

And the reason for the custom encryption was stated to me as,"It has just always been done this way, hey I didn't write it!"

Nice =]